# Where is CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR?

Tags: cmake

Is this variable always set to the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file that I run `cmake` on?

For example, if I wish to run `cmake` on a `CMakeLists.txt` file that exists in the directory above my current directory, I would go: `cmake ..`.

In this case, what is my CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR set to?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming that you have 2 folders `src` and `build` where `src` contains your projects and `build` is the empty folder that you just created so you can deploy your out-of-tree build in it: `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is the path to `src` where `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` points to `build`.

Note that if you are doing an in-tree build, the 2 cache entries get the same value.

link: [CMake Useful Variables](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) .

---

***EDIT***

for further clarifications

```
<some location>/src/CMakeLists.txt ( so *src* is the root of your project )
<some location>/build
```

if you do something like

```
cd <some location>/build
cmake <some location>/src
```

you are making an out-of-tree build where `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` get different values

Comment: Thank you for replying. But unfortunately I don't understand how this answer relates to my question above. I may be missing some basic information however.

Comment: @patchwork do you know what an out-of-tree build is ? it's when you configure and build your project in a folder that is not the original source folder, so when you say that you use `cmake ..` out of your source tree you are doing an out-of-tree build.

Comment: thanks, no I did not know what an out-of-tree build was. I still have not managed to connect the information you gave in your answer, with my question i.e. "Is this variable (CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) always set to the directory containing the CMakeLists.txt file that I run cmake on?" Anyway - I found out what CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR was by exporting it to the cache.

Comment: In your example above, where would you be putting the first CMakeLists.txt that gets run? In the `src` directory? I think this is why I can't relate this answer to my question - because I don't know where you are putting the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Does your answer imply that `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` is the folder from where I first run the `cmake` command? (In your example the `<some location>/build` folder...)

Comment: @patchwork yes, under linux the `cd` command is used to change directory and navigate the filesystem, so with `cd <some location>/build` I was implying that.

Comment: We may have got some crossed wires again. I already understand what the purpose of `cd` is. I will rephrase my question. "Does `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` automatically get set to be the path of the folder where I first run the `cmake` command? Your answer seems to imply that it does".

Comment: @patchwork Yes, I too was not sure what was going on with cmake, but you are correct, it does indeed set CMAKE_BINARY_DIR to your pwd when you first run it.  So, if your src is all in /opt/src/myproject and you have /opt/src/myproject/CMakeFiles.txt, then if you cd /tmp/build/debug and type cmake  /opt/src/myproject, you will find that CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=/tmp/build/debug